# setState() method doesn't update the widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

it is not updating my widget. If I click on the switch to turn _darkMode on the switch is always moving back (doesn't change)...

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SettingsScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const SettingsScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SettingsScreenState createState() => _SettingsScreenState();
}

class _SettingsScreenState extends State<SettingsScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    bool _darkMode = false;

return Container(
    child: ListView(
  children: [
    ListTile(
      title: const Text('Lights'),
      trailing: CupertinoSwitch(
        value: _darkMode,
        onChanged: (bool value) {
          setState(() {
            _darkMode = value;
            print('DarkMode: $_darkMode');
          });
        },
      ),
    ),
  ],
));
```

}
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

_darkMode must be a field in the widget state. Move it outside the build method:

```
  class _SettingsScreenState extends State<SettingsScreen> {
  
  bool _darkMode = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
```

Comment: @JanHecker if the answer from Ignacio solved your issue, please mark the question as solved so others can find it in that state.